# Is it possible to Invoke an exported "private" method in c++

Tags: c++, dll, export, private

Is it possible to invoke a private method of a class exported from a DLL?
Will it be hidden from people who would like to use it but are not supposed to?
thanks :)

Comment: I'd be surprised if the compiler let you mark a private member function as exported.

Comment: @MerickOWA: C++ knows nothing about DLLs, so it's possible, in the language, to implement a class functions across many dlls (unless a compiler forbids it). I think it won't since you can spread functions a cross translation units (obj-files), so spreading them across DLLs is an issue for the linker, which doesn't enforce much C++-ness at all, AFAICT (except to de-mange mangled function names in error messages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible**, but you need to use dirty casting tricks or rely on semi-undefined behaviour, but for certainty you can call an exported function, no matter it's private/public status.

The language does not provide security against malicious attackers. It will help everyone play by the rules, but it will not guard against those who try to break the system.

For instance:

- use `GetProcAddress()` to get the function's address, cast it to the right member function type, and call it.
- create a modified header file of the class, declaring everything as public (or just add a static function, `void crowbar()` ), compile against that. (Undefined behaviour, since you're violating the One Defintion Rule, but it will probably work...)

**Do not rely on C++ private keyword for security.**

Comment: There is no "right member function type" for a pointer obtained through `GetProcAddress`.  In most cases the actual call will require writing some assembly.  But it is possible.

Comment: @Ben: I assumed calling a non-virtual member function (if it's a member function at all) with thiscall is pretty straightforward. Are there other issues? (Just curious)

Comment: @Macke: Yeah, you have to pass the `this` pointer somehow, and the `thiscall` calling convention doesn't match either `cdecl` or `stdcall`, since `thiscall` passes the `this` pointer in a register rather than using the stack.  It might be compatible with `fastcall`, can't remember.

Comment: @Ben: I was assuming you could cast function pointers across calling conventions. If not, then assembly is required. As you say, you  need `thiscall`, but that should be implicit in a ptr-to-member-function type.

Comment: @Macke: Pointer-to-member-function has support for vtable lookups, virtual base classes requiring `this`-pointer-adjustments, etc.  A pointer-to-member-function is not a function pointer.  `GetProcAddress` returns a function pointer, not a pointer-to-member.  The result of `GetProcAddress` needs to be cast to the correct function pointer type (including calling convention), but the correct type can't be written in C++, I don't think.

Comment: Note that virtual support has to exist regardless of whether the target member function is virtual or not, because they aren't part of the pmf type.  The code calling the pmf has no way of knowing whether the pmf was created from a virtual or non-virtual function.

Comment: @Ben: Right. I knew about the need for that, but didn't properly connect the dots, so to speak. It'd be an interesting exercise to see what's needed to get it to work though. :)

Answer (score 1):

If it appears in the DLL's export table, it can be invoked by using `GetProcAddress` and calling the returned function pointer.  There are some technical hurdles to get the right calling convention, but it is possible (most likely some assembly language will be required).

Strictly speaking, any function for which the compiler generates an out-of-line instance can be called by any native code.  Being exported by a DLL just makes it far easier to find the address of the code for the function.